# Get all text which is on screen in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios5, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I need to get all words, which are visible on screen from **UIWebView**.
My **UIWebView** have html content.

Someone can help me please.

Comment: Are you looking for all the html of the page that is being shown, or just the html that is visible on the screen at that moment? and do you want only the text or the entire html?

Comment: i want only text which is vislbe on the screen at moment.

Comment: I don't think there is a method to call where one could get this. The only way i can think of is to parse the full html and go from there. But im not sure as i have never tried something like that

Comment: u found any solution for that?

Answer (score 9):

Use following way that will give you all text of `UIWebView`.

```
NSString *yourstring = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                  @"document.body.innerText"];
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: i need to get text which is visible on screen

Comment: Dude i checked it's give all text that are visible in web view. Try to open http://www.google.com and compare the out put web vie text.

Comment: ya it gives me all content of html. not only visible text i tried it.

Comment: This worked for me with the pages but I only tested on Wikipedia pages

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
NSString *str = [self.youWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                  @"document.body.textContent"];
```

Comment: thank you but i don't need to get all content of HTML, i need to get on screen text.